# How to test if a page has a date picker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I'm spec-ing my form that will have some date pickers.

`expect(page).to have_select('Start date')` and `expect(page).to have_select('deal[start_date]')` both return no matches. The latter makes sense given that the html for date pickers is a little funky (`name="deal[start_date(2i)]`)

`expect(page).to have_date_select('deal[start_date]')` says that Capybara doesn't recognize `has_date_select`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Capybaras `has_select?` predicate and `have_select` matcher look for HTML `<select>` elements.  Depending on what you mean by a date picker you'll have to use a matcher that would match the correct type of element, or `have_selector` if there isn't a specific matcher.  If what you are actually checking for is an `<input type="date">` element with an associated label containing the text 'Start date' then you can use the `have_field` matcher:

```
expect(page).to have_field 'Start date', type: 'date'
```

If you're using the Rails date_select view helper it produces HTML like

```
<div class="field">
  <label for="post_start_date">Start date</label>
  <select id="post_start_date_1i" name="post[start_date(1i)]">
     <option value="2014">2014</option>
     <option value="2015">2015</option>
     ...
  </select>
  <select id="post_start_date_2i" name="post[start_date(2i)]">
     <option value="1" selected="selected">January</option>
     <option value="2">February</option>
     ...
  </select>
  <select id="post_start_date_3i" name="post[start_date(3i)]">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     ...
  </select>
</div>
```

You can see from looking at that HTML that the <label> element isn't actually associated with any of the form fields (the `for` attribute doesn't match an id) which means you won't be able to match the <select> elements using the label text.  Instead you'd need to use either the id or name and match them individually

```
expect(page).to have_select('post_start_date_1i')
expect(page).to have_select('post[start_date(2i)]')
...
```

or you could use the `id` filter with a regex and a count to check that there are 3 elements matching like

```
expect(page).to have_select(id: /^post_start_date_[123]i$/, count: 3)
```

Note, that's not technically as 'correct' as doing them individually since you could actually have 3 elements with id of post_start_date_1i and it would still pass, but in that case your HTML would also be invalid.

If that's not the type of HTML element you're checking for then you'll need to provide the HTML to get an exact answer.